Bounds of integration for the Wishart density
I once took a course that included zillions of exercises concerning the Wishart distribution, but as far as I recall, never mentioned the Wishart density. I asked something about that in this question, in which I mentioned that bounds of integration might be messy.
A reply said the measure with respect to which one integrates (in the non-singular case) is
$$
\prod_{i,j\,:\,1\,\le\,i\,\le\,j\,\le\,p} dx_{i,j}.
$$
My question here is about those "messy" bounds of integration.
I'm going to make a guess and see whether someone who knows something can confirm it or deny it or (maybe the best option) improve upon it.
We are integrating over the space of matrices $(x_{i,j})_{i,j \, \in\, \{1,\,\ldots,\,p\}}$ that are symmetric and positive-definite.
Suppose such a matrix is
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} \underset{p_1\times p_1} A & \underset{p_1\times p_2} B \\[8pt] \underset{p_2\times p_1}{B^T} & \underset{p_2\times p_2}C \end{array} \right].
$$
Then $A$ and $C$ are symmetric and positive-definite, and $B$ must be such as to make the entire matrix above positive-definite.
There is this one-to-one correspondence:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} A & B \\[8pt] B^T & C \end{array} \right] \longleftrightarrow \left( \underset{p_1\times p_1} A,\quad \underset{p_2\times p_1} {B^T A^{-1}}, \quad \underset{p_2\times p_2} {C- B^T A^{-1} B} \right) = (J,K,L).
$$
So $J$ and $L$ are positive-definite.
The second component of this triple occurs in an expression for conditional expected value and the third is the corresponding conditional variance.
It follows that
\begin{align}
A & = J, \\
B & = JK^T, \\
C & = L + KJK^T.
\end{align}
The domain of $(J,K,L)\mapsto(A,B,C)$ is a Cartesian product whose first and third factors are the sets of all positive-definite symmetric real matrices of the appropriate sizes and whose second factor is the set of (here is the interesting part) all $p_2\times p_1$ real matrices $K.$ (Easy exercise: Prove that.)
So we have reduced the problem of bounds of integration to that of bounds of integration for smaller positive-definite symmetric real matrices, plus integrating over a space of matrices in which the bounds for every entry are $-\infty$ and $+\infty.$
This can be iterated until we have a Cartesian product of $p=p_1+p_2$ factors each of which is $(0,+\infty),$ and $\binom p2$ factors each of which is $(-\infty,+\infty).$
My questions are: Is this useful? Is this a standard technique?

\begin{align}
& \int\limits_\text{bounds} f \left( \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & x_{1,3} \ x_{1,2} & x_{2,2} & x_{2,3} \ x_{1,3} & x_{2,3} & x_{3,3} \end{array} \right] \right) ,dx_{1,1},dx_{1,2} , dx_{1,3} , dx_{2,2} , dx_{2,3} , dx_{3,3} \ & \text{The bounds on the 6-tuple of variables above are messy.} \ {} \
= {} & \int\limits_{(0,+\infty)} \left( \int\limits_{\mathbb R} \int\limits_{\mathbb R} \left( ,,,\int\limits_\text{bounds} \cdots , dx_{2,2} , dx_{2,3} , dx_{3,3}  \right) , dx_{1,2} , dx_{1,3}  \right) , dx_{1,1} \end{align}

\begin{align} & \text{where the “$,\cdots,$” above are what is below:} \ {} \
& f\left( x_{1,1}, \left[
\begin{array}{c} x_{1,2}/x_{1,1} \ x_{1,3}/x_{1,1} \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{cc} x_{2,2}\left( \frac{ x_{1,1} - x_{2,2}}{x_{1,1}} \right), & x_{2,3}\left( \frac{ x_{1,1} - x_{2,2}}{x_{1,1}} \right) \ x_{2,3}\left( \frac{ x_{1,1} - x_{2,2}}{x_{1,1}} \right), & \frac{ x_{3,3} x_{1,1} - x_{2,3}^2 }{x_{1,1}} \end{array} \right] \right)
\end{align}
and where it says "bounds," those are still messy until the next step.

This looks a lot like Theorem 3.2.10 from Muirhead's book

This book also describes how to integrate over the weird bounds with wedge products

@Taylor : Is there any chance you can state that theorem here?

Both of the expressions in comments above that look like $f\Big( \cdots\cdots\Big)$ should be construed as the same function of the six variables $x_{i,j}.$

Here is the requested theorem

You would probably be interested in the proof, too. It runs over a few pages.





Multiplying differentials is done in the skew-symmetric sense, not in the typical commutative way. This "wedge" product is described in the previous chapter of the book.

I've seen this theorem before, but never a proof using the density function. If an answer to my question is in this, it's in the proof rather than in the theorem. I'll look that over.

I have the most wonderful proof of this sublime theorem, but it is too long to be written in this narrow margin.
Or, more precisely, I have this reduction of the problem of integrating over the space of $3\times3$ positive-definite symmetric real matrices to the problem of integrating over the space of $2\times2$ symmetric real matrices:
$$
\int\limits_{\mathbf S^3_{++}}
f\left( \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & x_{1,3} \\
x_{1,2} & x_{2,2} & x_{2,3} \\
x_{1,3} & x_{2,3} & x_{3,3}
\end{array} \right] \right)
\, d(x_{1,1}, x_{1,2}, x_{1,3}, x_{2,2}, x_{2,3}, x_{3,3})
$$
$$
= \int\limits_{(0,+\infty)}
\left(\,\,\, \int\limits_{\mathbb R^2}
\left( \,\,\, \int\limits_{\mathbf S^2_{++}}
f\left( \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
t & tu_1 & tu_2 \\ tu_1 & v_{1,1} + tu_1^2
& v_{1,2} + tu_1u_2 \\
tu_2 & v_{1,2} + tu_1u_2 & v_{2,2} + tu_2^2
\end{array} \right] \right)
\, d(v_{1,1}, v_{1,2}, v_{2,2} ) \right)
t^2 \, d(u_1,u_2) \right) \, dt
$$
I was going to post this as a comment but it wouldn't fit. The margin was too narrow.
